# Is it possible to update two variable values in case then statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to update two things together using case statement..

suppose I have two variable and both variables were initialized with 0. Now 1 want to update 1st variable with 1 and 2nd variable with 4.

Case when id>2 then (update both var values).

is it possible if not could you suggest alternate solution.

Comment: Please, provide some contextual code snippet. Variables are part of PL/SQL, which is a procedural language, and we do not update them, but assign some values (if they are not structured), because they have no persistency. In general we update tables, that have no variables, but fields

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `update` data, a `case` doesn't seem necessary:

```
update t
    set var1 = 1,
        var2 = 4
    where id = 2;  -- or id > 2 if that is the actual condition
```

Comment: I created the dummy scenario of my actual requirement. I can use only case statement on my code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CASE statements in PL/SQL can be used to assign values to multiple variables:

```
declare
    x number := 42;
    y number;
    z number;
begin
    case
        when x > 2 then
            y := 43;
            z := 44;
    end case; 
end;
```

That isn't "updating", though.

If this is about the SQL UPDATE statement though, CASE can only return one value.

Answer (score 0):

Variables? That's PL/SQL, then. If so, see if this helps:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    id number := 3;
  3    v1 number := 0;
  4    v2 number := 0;
  5  begin
  6    select case when id > 2 then 1 else v1 end,
  7           case when id > 2 then 4 else v2 end
  8      into v1, v2
  9      from dual;
 10    dbms_output.put_line('v1 = ' || v1 ||', v2 = ' || v2);
 11  end;
 12  /
v1 = 1, v2 = 4                              --> for ID = 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> l2
  2*   id number := 3;
SQL> c/3/1                                  --> change ID from 3 to 1
  2*   id number := 1;
SQL> /
v1 = 0, v2 = 0                              --> for ID = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```